# IIS Search Engine Optimization Toolkit isn't showing up in my IIS7

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I downloaded the Search Engine Optimization Tookit using the Web Platform Installer.

Most of the plugins I've installed (i.e. IIS Rewrite 2.0) have installed, no problem -- I love that tool!

But the **Search Engine Optimization Toolkit** for IIS -- which I REALLY want -- doesn't show up in my IIS Manager. I downloaded from the Web Platform Installer, I've rebooted, etc,. but still, nothing.

I'm running on Windows 7 (I heard this could be an issue, but that was from a post back in 2009), and everything on my computer runs well.

Does anyone know if I can get this on my IIS on Windows 7?  Thank you for your time in reading this, and any guidance would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking in the wrong area of my IIS.  I was looking in my website, and not the Owner-PC section of the IIS, where it gets installed.